# Error : conflicting types for scandir and scandir64 while installing scratchbox 2 for LTP

Tags: linux, scratchbox

I followed the steps for installing scratch box 2;

git clone http://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/sbox2.git

```
./autogen.sh

cd sbox2

./configure --prefix=/opt/sb2

make install
```

But while installing, it shows conflicts for `scandir` and `scandir64`.

It will be grateful if someone could answer this. 
Thanks.

Comment: Do you run 32-bit or 64-bit system? command to check is `uname -m`

Comment: @the.Legend I use virtual box ubuntu 64bit.

uname -a

Linux ltp-VirtualBox 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Check if correct version of Glibc is installed. The package is rather old so you might need to downgrade. Play around with LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point it to correct  versions.
As per README it will try to support both 32 and 64-bit scandirs on x86_64 system so make sure libc6-dev-i386, lib32gcc1 and such are installed